# Spring Batch to write file locally

Tags: spring, io, spring-batch

I've got a job that creates an output file which is usually FTP'd. I want this file written locally so it can be accessed by the next step instead of FTP'd

I've done some searching and can really only find info on writing remote. Do I need to write a step? I want the `bus567SetupStep` to write the file locally, so then `bus568SetupStep` can go read that file and do it's work. I have no need for the `putFtpStep`

```
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class BusbspaBatchConfiguration {

    // tag::jobstep[]
    @Bean(name = "mccBUSBSPAjob")
    public Job mccEcmPurgejob(JobBuilderFactory jobFactory, //
            @Qualifier("bus567SetupStep") Step bus567SetupStep, //
            @Qualifier("bus568SetupStep") Step bus568SetupStep, //
            @Qualifier("callM204Step") Step callM204Step, //
            @Qualifier("putFtpFilesStep") Step putFtpStep, //
            @Qualifier("teardownStep") Step teardownStep, //
            @Autowired SingleInstanceListener listener) {
        return jobFactory.get("mccBUSBSPAjob") //
                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer()) //
                .listener(listener) //
                .start(bus567SetupStep) //
                .next(callM204Step) //
                .next(bus568SetupStep) //
                .next(callM204Step) //
                .next(putFtpStep) //
                .next(teardownStep) //
                .build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "bus567SetupStep")
    public Step bus567SetupStep(StepBuilderFactory stepFactory, Bus567SetupTasklet task) {
        return stepFactory.get("bus567SetupStep") //
                .tasklet(task) //
                .allowStartIfComplete(true).build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "bus568SetupStep")
    public Step bus568SetupStep(StepBuilderFactory stepFactory, Bus568SetupTasklet task) {
        return stepFactory.get("bus568SetupStep") //
                .tasklet(task) //
                .allowStartIfComplete(true).build();
    }

    // end::jobstep[]
}
```

Comment: What prevents you from making the `bus567SetupStep` write the file locally?

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine I guess that's what I don't understand, how to write or implement logic to allow the step to write the file locally

Comment: If your step is a tasklet then you can use any java code that writes a file to local disk. If your step is a chunk oriented step then you can use the `FlatFileItemWriter` with a `Resource` pointing to a local file.